# Bad substitution when passing parameter to shell script in Jenkins

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy

I'm attempting to pass value of a variable by setting the stdOut of a shell script.
However in The console of Jenkins displays of followings:

```
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Feature Segunda)
[Pipeline] echo
${params.Segunda}
[Pipeline] sh
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/pruebaParametrizada@tmp/durable-71aead85/script.sh: 1: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/pruebaParametrizada@tmp/durable-71aead85/script.sh: Bad substitution
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] echo
Building finished successfully
```

I use to escape the quotes, nothing works. I get a bad substitution error. I've also tried without double quotes.

If I hardcode in the shell script arguments, it runs fine.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        string(defaultValue: "", description: '', name: 'One')
        string(defaultValue: "", description: '', name: 'Two')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Git Checkout') {
            steps {
                git credentialsId: 'personal-github', url: 'https:xxx'
            }
        }
        stage('Maven Compile') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn clean compile'
            }
        }
        stage('Test One') {
            steps {
                //ERROR
                sh 'mvn test -Dcucumber.options="-t @${params.One}"'

                //This Works
                //sh 'mvn test -Dcucumber.options="-t @One"'
            }
        }      
    }
    post {
        always { 
            echo 'Building finished successfully'
            cucumber failedFeaturesNumber: -1, 
            failedScenariosNumber: -1, 
            failedStepsNumber: -1, 
            fileIncludePattern: '**/*.json', 
            jsonReportDirectory: 'target/cucumber/', 
            pendingStepsNumber: -1, 
            reportTitle: 'test features', 
            skippedStepsNumber: -1, 
            sortingMethod: 'ALPHABETICAL', 
            undefinedStepsNumber: -1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Variables aren't replaced in single quotes in groovy.

Comment: @tkausl Also works with doble quotes 

`"mvn test -Dcucumber.options="-t @${params.One}"" `

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67073830/bad-substitution-error-while-passing-jenkins-parameter-value-in-shell-script-ins/67074024#67074024

Comment: @MichaelKemmerzell Thanks for you response, I replace single colons ' ' with doble colons " " and works properly

Comment: @JuanJoseEstrella Great to hear that! Feel free to give an upvote :P

Comment: @MichaelKemmerzell I tried to give you an upvote, but, doesn't show me the option about your comment, sorry :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to pass parameters as follows`

`sh """mvn test -Dcucumber.options='-t @${params.One}'"""`

Thanks to all, for responses.